# How to add an custom add-on in OpenERP mobile (Android)?

Tags: android, openerp-7

I'm new to OpenERP Android. I got an empty OpenERP project which includes some simple add-ons such as idea, meeting, messages, note in com.opererp.addons package of the project.
The only thing I want know is how to create a custom add-on. I've some Android experience. But OpenERP mobile seems difficult for me. Please give me some idea or example add-ons download links. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are already official doc for that so you can develop your own openerp app.

### [OpenERP Mobile Framework Doc](http://mobile.openerp.co.in/)

Thanks